# Find distance between a point and a catenary curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I'm not a mathematician, but a programmer who needs to understand how I can calculate the distance.
I have a catenary curve defined with parameters `a`, `p`, and `q`. Also, I have defined the start and end of the curve.
The question is how can I calculate the distance between any point and the catenary curve?
For now, I have a catenary divided into many small segments and treat them like straight lines. This solution is very slow because I have to iterate through all segments and choose the closest one.

@Edit:
I have parameters of catenary and a few points in 3D space. Now I have to calculate the distance from these points to the catenary curve.
My curve is determined by:
$$a.\cosh(\frac{x - p}{a}) + q$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x_0,y_0)$ is your point, you need to find the $x$ which minimizes $(x -x_0)^2+(a.\cosh(\frac{x-p}{a})+q-y_0)^2$. To do this, differentiate and put the result equal to $0$. This gives

$$2(x-x_0)+2\sinh(\frac{x-p}{a})\Big(a.\cosh(\frac{x-p}{a})+q-y_0\Big)=0.$$

This will need a numerical method to solve, like Newton's Method.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. So the second function you wrote is derivative of the frist one?

Comment: @Raffallo Yes. The first one is the square of the distance between points $(x_0, y_0)$ and $\big(x, a.\cosh(\frac{x - p}{a}) + q\big)$. The second one is its derivative, that used to find its minimum.

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understand everything. So basically Newton's Method is relies on checking if `h = func(x) / derivFunc(x)` is close to zero. If not we change `x = x - h` and check again?
If so, it means that I did something wrong.

Comment: To solve func(x) = 0 you iterate X_next = X_previous -func(X_previous)/derivfunc(X_previous) with initial value X_0. The initial value could be the x coord of one end point of the curve. Your iteration stopping condition is func((X_previous)<epsilon. You put the x you finally get into the distance squared formula. If your x is outside the curve range then the closest point will be an endpoint.

Comment: That should be the modulus of func(X_previous) is less than epsilon

Comment: @Paul Thanks, man! So basically I did the same thing, but it's going to `NaN` in my case. `a.cosh` in the formula is `a * cosh` or `acosh`?

Comment: $a*cosh$ in the formulas

Comment: I don't know why, but it does not work for me. I'm getting `NaN` when calculating. My sample data: point `(10.0, 10.0)`, initial `X_0 = 999.0`, `p = 290.98887656976382`, `q = -1081.4643915762172`, `a = 1392.8392903379133`. At 363 iteration I'm getting `NaN`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138606/discussion-between-raffallo-and-paul).